# Performance issue of calculation for the weight for ego net

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

We have the below Graph Data below. only 5 Vertexes but we have many Edges. How can I handle below Querys?I would like to get the path from one node to one other. I just want to get the cycle path and calculate sum of the weight of the ego. The cycle will be from one to the other and one to itself. And I'd like to filter the sum of the calculation of the weight.

```
suresh       = graph.addVertex(label,'person','uuid','7bff1bc0-cef1-1033-8f28-d99da6cfd8a9')
robin_niu    = graph.addVertex(label,'person','uuid','e3348740-d37f-1031-8b5b-89fbb6fdad64')
hujunjie     = graph.addVertex(label,'person','uuid','5e5139c0-dbe7-102e-8780-bedba724cbf7')
clintpollitt = graph.addVertex(label,'person','uuid','d92c6340-f98b-1035-85d7-bee5d5cc5ebe')
yanjuqi      = graph.addVertex(label,'person','uuid','2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9')

suresh.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-11-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-11-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-11-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('ProfilesReportingToChain',clintpollitt,'date','2016-12-01T00:00:00Z','weight',5)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
suresh.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)

clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-01-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-11-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
clintpollitt.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)

yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-10-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-14T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-15T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-10-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-10-02T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-10-04T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-10-05T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
yanjuqi.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)

robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',hujunjie,'date','2017-10-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-14T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-15T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-10-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
robin_niu.addEdge('ProfilesReportingToChain',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-02T00:00:00Z','weight',5)
robin_niu.addEdge('ProfilesColleague',hujunjie,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',2)

hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',robin_niu,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-12-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-11-11T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',clintpollitt,'date','2017-12-12T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-10-13T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-11-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',suresh,'date','2017-01-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-14T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-12-15T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('Communication',yanjuqi,'date','2017-10-01T00:00:00Z','weight',1)
hujunjie.addEdge('ProfilesReportingToChain',yanjuqi,'date','2016-10-02T00:00:00Z','weight',5)
hujunjie.addEdge('ProfilesColleague',robin_niu,'date','2017-10-03T00:00:00Z','weight',2)
```

below query can't work very well. How can I fix this issue?

```
g.V().has('uuid','e3348740-d37f-1031-8b5b-89fbb6fdad64').as('v').
  repeat(outE().as('e').inV().as('v')).
    until(has('uuid','2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9')).
  store('a').
    by('uuid').
  store('a').
    by(select(all, 'v').unfold().values('uuid').fold()).
  store('a').
    by(select(all, 'e').unfold().
       store('x').
         by(union(values('weight'),
                  select('x').count(local)).fold()).
       cap('x').
       store('a').
         by(unfold().limit(local, 1).fold()).unfold().
       sack(assign).
         by(constant(1d)).
       sack(div).
         by(union(constant(1d),
                  tail(local, 1)).sum()).
       sack(mult).
         by(limit(local, 1)).
       sack().sum()).
  cap('a')
```

Comment: i know that query you post at the bottom quite well - you say it doesn't work very well, but don't say why. is it performance related?

Comment: sorry - the title of your question says "performance" so I guess that's the issue. how slow are you finding this traversal to be in your environment?

Comment: Actually，it is hooked in our environment while we execute this script. And I have made index for uuid. any other comments/suggestion?

Comment: This script can't work. We tried to find another way to fix this issue.

Comment: but now we didn't find a good way to solve this hooked issue.

Comment: sorry - "hooked" - i'm not sure i understand what that means in the way you are using it.

Comment: Hooked means ,it is pending at the screen. no any output and no result I can get. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query is going to run forever, as your graph contains cyclic paths, which are not considered by your query. I assume, that you only care about the shortest path (otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to fill up the `a` collection IMO). A simple change will fix your query:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('uuid','e3348740-d37f-1031-8b5b-89fbb6fdad64').as('v').
......1>   repeat(outE().as('e').inV().as('v')).
......2>     until(has('uuid','2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9').
......3>             or().cyclicPath()).
......4>   has('uuid','2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9').limit(1).
......5>   store('a').
......6>     by('uuid').
......7>   store('a').
......8>     by(select(all, 'v').unfold().values('uuid').fold()).
......9>   store('a').
.....10>     by(select(all, 'e').unfold().
.....11>        store('x').
.....12>          by(union(values('weight'),
.....13>                   select('x').count(local)).fold()).
.....14>        cap('x').
.....15>        store('a').
.....16>          by(unfold().limit(local, 1).fold()).unfold().
.....17>        sack(assign).
.....18>          by(constant(1d)).
.....19>        sack(div).
.....20>          by(union(constant(1d),
.....21>                   tail(local, 1)).sum()).
.....22>        sack(mult).
.....23>          by(limit(local, 1)).
.....24>        sack().sum()).
.....25>   cap('a')
==>[2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9,[e3348740-d37f-1031-8b5b-89fbb6fdad64,2d9fba40-74c7-1033-8e84-d3a6c90ad2e9],[5],5.0]
```